# Create Targetprocess items when a case is created in Salesforce (and viceversa)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, targetprocess

I know there are some bots and 3rd party integrations which handle such processes, but I was interested in building one myself to avoid extra expenses.

We have a Targetprocess environment and a Salesforce environment. We'd like to connect the two of them so that, for example, when someone creates a case in Salesforce, it also creates an item in TP.

I've researched a bit about it but I only ever come across those 3rd party solutions. I also know that it's possible to connect TP and gitlab (for example), so I figure that a similar integration with Salesforce would be possible as well. But I am at a lost as to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The key word defining the process you're interested in is *integration*. If Targetprocess doesn't supply an out-of-the-box integration tool and you do not want to use a third-party product, you'll have to build code or declarative automation on *both* Targetprocess and Salesforce to have each communicate with the other's API when specific events happen.

Bidirectional integration is a huge, complex area that often requires deep subject-matter expertise in both systems as well as your overall enterprise data strategy; if you're not already familiar with building automation in both environments, this may prove to be a big lift. Far and away the easiest solution is to use an existing product that provides this service.